# horizontal scroll menu scroll() event instead of animate()? jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm programming this scrolbar menu....Its almost done, but still have this issue

**PROBLEM**

**1)** It doesnt recognize both ends....

**2)** I want `.scrollmenu` to maintain `overflow:auto;`

**3)** In the current fiddle, the nav buttons doesnt scroll `.scrollmenu` just move them. I want to know if possible to use `(".scrollmenu").scroll()` instead of  `(".scrollmenu").animate()`

```js
$("#left").click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
     $(".scrollmenu").animate({ "left": "+=60px" }, "slow" );

});

$("#right").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   $(".scrollmenu").animate({ "left": "-=60px" }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 0px solid red;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;

}

.scrollmenu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

#right,
#left {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">&#8592;</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="scrollmenu">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#support">Support</a>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
          <a href="#base">Base</a>
          <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
          <a href="#more">More</a>
          <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
          <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
          <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
          <a href="#people">People</a>
          <a href="#work">Work</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id="right">&#8594;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you only need to change `left` to `scrollLeft` in your code, this behaves exactly like a visible scrollbar (so you also need to invert the values).

```js
$("#left").click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
     $(".scrollmenu").animate({ "scrollLeft": "-=60px" }, "slow" );

});

$("#right").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   $(".scrollmenu").animate({ "scrollLeft": "+=60px" }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 0px solid red;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;

}

.scrollmenu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

#right,
#left {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">&#8592;</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="scrollmenu">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#support">Support</a>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
          <a href="#base">Base</a>
          <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
          <a href="#more">More</a>
          <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
          <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
          <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
          <a href="#people">People</a>
          <a href="#work">Work</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id="right">&#8594;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok I understand, but in this case the nav buttons only moves the `.scrollmenu` once?

Comment: No, it works everytime you click on it, but only to the bounds of the inner element (you can't overscroll). You can also add a `.stop()` right before the animate calls to stop and start the animation again after a button was clicked.

Comment: Also if you really don't want to use `animate` at all, you can modify the scrollLeft property directly by changing it to `.scrollLeft('-=60px')` but this way you lose the smooth scrolling effect.

Comment: I'm on  chrome right now testing your fiddle, but the nav buttons only moves the `.scrollmenu` only once. after that the doesnt move it anymore...

Comment: ok...on the fiddle here doesnt work properly.I've tested on my site and works perfect.I think you won a marked answer. thank you!!

Comment: I started playing around with it here on SO but still can't get it work, even if it worked in my own file. I'm glad it worked for you as well. Thanks :)